# Fast 1D median filter in OpenCV (or in c++)

Tags: opencv, median

I've been prototyping some image (8bit) processing that involves the median filtering with a rectangular kernel {1,25} and I found out that OpenCV [medianBlur](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=medianblur#medianblur) only accepts square kernels.

I've discovered a [constant time median algorithm](http://nomis80.org/ctmf.html) but again it works with a square kernel. Do you guys know I could implement my 1D median using OpenCV or standard c++?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [This](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Median_filter#C) is pretty easy to port to C++ and works very good.

Comment: I guess you can use `sepFilter2D()` to apply 1D kernels, with an identity kernel for one dimension, but that would destroy your concern of efficiency.